# Terra Focal Function uses non-neighbor values

Tags: r, mean

I have issues understanding the operating of the terra::focal function. I created the following raster:

```
r<-rast(ncol=5,nrow=5,vals=1:25)
r_df <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
colnames(r_df) <- c("x", "y", "z")

ggplot(r_df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) +
geom_tile() +
geom_text(label = r_df$z, size = 4, colour = "black") +
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                   limits = c(min(r_df$z), max(r_df$z)),
                   midpoint = median(r_df$z)) +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_y_reverse() +
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
theme(legend.position = "none") +
theme()
```

[image]

Now I want to calculate for each cell the sum of the neighboring cells values:

```
weight_matrix <- matrix(1, nrow=3, ncol=3)
weight_matrix[2,2] <- NA
r<-terra::focal(r,weight_matrix, fun=sum, na.policy="all", na.rm=TRUE, expand=FALSE, fillvalue=NA)
```

Which then yields the following matrix:

[image]

I do not understand how the values on the outside of the raster are calculated. Looking at the bottom left cell, I would expect the value to be 15 (2 + 6 + 7), however, it is equal to 30. It seems like the values from the bottom right are included in the sum. I played around with the parameters but don't think I get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ggplot function is hiding the X axis values (and reversing the Y axis for some reason?). When I used a simpler function that didn't, I saw the problem.

```
plr <- function(r){
    rd = as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
    plot(r)
    text(rd[,1],rd[,2], as.character(rd[,3]))
}
```

When I plot your `r`, its from -180 to 180, so it wraps around the sphere, and `focal` is respecting that by wrapping the weight matrix across the 180:-180 boundary:

[image]

As a demonstration, I made a matrix of all 1 values and smoothed it with your function call:

```
> r1 = rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, vals=1)
> s1 = terra::focal(r1,weight_matrix, fun=sum, na.policy="all", na.rm=TRUE, expand=FALSE, fillvalue=NA)
> plr(s1)
```

[image]

But if I change the CRS to 27700, so instead of being a -180 to 180 degree raster covering the globe, its a 360 x 180 metre tiny plot of ocean off the coast of the UK, I get a different result:

```
> crs(r1) = "epsg:27700"
> s1 = terra::focal(r1,weight_matrix, fun=sum, na.policy="all", na.rm=TRUE, expand=FALSE, fillvalue=NA)
> plr(s1)
```

[image]

If you want to stop if wrapping round the world, give it a missing CRS and replace the CRS back on the computed raster. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want a focal operation to not look round the back of the world but here's how to do that:

```
> r1 = rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, vals=1)
> # save original crs and set to nothing
> c1 = crs(r1) ; crs(r1) = "" 
> # do the focal now on a raster with no CRS so focal doesn't know the
> # earth is round
> s1 = terra::focal(r1,weight_matrix, fun=sum, na.policy="all", na.rm=TRUE, expand=FALSE, fillvalue=NA)
> # restore the non-flat earth
> crs(s1) = c1 ; crs(r1) = c1
> plot(s1)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I do understand it!